# Can terms be divided by the differential dx?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(y-x)dx+4xdy=0$$$$y-x+4x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$$$4x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x$$
My differential equations book says that by dividing the first equation by the differential $dx$, second and third equation is given. And each of three equations has same differential form. But It's not allowed to regard $\frac{dx}{dy}$ as just fraction and no any terms of equations shouldn't be divided by $dx$(I think it's true). Why the author divide that equation using $dx$?

Comment: This can be formalized using differential forms. This is not something that can be explained in a comment. There are questions on this forum about it, search for the most upvoted ones. The bottom line is: "dividing" by $dx$ when solving ODEs will produce correct results.

Comment: It is true that if $\Delta x$ is a tiny change in the value of $x$ and $\Delta y$ is the corresponding change in the value of $y$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} \approx \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. So, these arguments that involve manipulating $dx$ and $dy$ aren't crazy. Just replace the equal signs with approximately equal signs and hope that "in the limit" you will have exact equality in the equations you derive.

Comment: The aim is to solve the original equation to obtain $y$ as a not necessarily unique function of $x$. If $y=f(x)$ is such a solution, $dy=f^\prime(x)dx=\frac{dy}{dx}dx$, so our starting-point can be written in the form $g(x,\,y)dx=0$. This reduces to $g(x,\,y,\,y^\prime)=0$, the same equation obtained by dividing the original by $dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation defines a direction field by assigning every point $(x,y)$ the line of $(v_x,v_y)$ where $(y-x)v_x+4xv_y=0$. Any curve that is tangent to this direction field in any point is a solution. The advantage of this form is that it is independent of the parametrization of the curves.

Selecting a cut, a continuous vector field that lies in each point on the direction line, then fixes specific parametrizations of the solution curves by the associated ODE system. This can be done in a globally smooth fashion, like in $v_x=4x$, $v_y=x-y$. The curves that have this vector field as tangents satisfy the system of differential equations 
$$
\dot x=v_x=4x,\\
\dot y=v_y=x-y.
$$
This is accidentially linear and can be solved as linear system or as a sequence of scalar linear DE.

One could also select other vector fields that are not smooth everywhere and thus may not fill the solution curves of the previous system completely. One such selection is to scale the previous field so that $v_x=1$ and thus $x=t+c$. Then
$$
\dot y=y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=v_y=\frac{x-y}{4x}.
$$

Comment: I searched the `slope field` and other questions about the `differential form` to understand your answer, but still don't know. I'm accustomed to the arithmetic without any axiom or a fundamental basis of calculus, what should I know before in order to grasp your article?